# Unable to connect to local azure webrole but can on staging

Tags: azure, servicestack, azure-web-roles

I have a servicestack webrole as part of a cloudservice.

When I deploy to staging it all works as expected.

When I run locally from VS2012 it's not able to connect (Chrome says "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.15:82/metadata"

This is tricky as I can't debug locally.

Comment: why are you on `127.0.0.15`. that's kinda strange. do you have lots  of orphaned releases that haven't been tidied up ?

Comment: this wouldn't surprise me, how can I find out.  (new to .net web apps)

Comment: reboot :-) (no seriously)

Comment: BRB...   We'll see if it works.

Comment: Hello, that was fun. It certainly fixed the 127.0.0.15 problem, but weirdly it tried port 81 and couldn't connect. I changed to port 80 and away it went all happy.